# Pandas dataframe to excel not working in docker

Tags: python, docker, plotly-dash

I've built a dash app which I've then saved to docker, and when I try to export the data table using:

```
pd.DataFrame(rows).to_excel(file, index=False)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/src/app/app.py", line 246, in update_output
        pd.DataFrame(rows).to_excel(file, index=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2023, in to_excel
        formatter.write(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 742, in write
        writer.save()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 43, in save
        return self.book.save(self.path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 392, in save
        save_workbook(self, filename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
        archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
        self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/file_name.xlsx'
```

The code works fine when I run it in python, it only breaks in docker container. I installed openpyxl from the requirements file.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you mounted the volume to which you are trying to write the file?

Comment: Almost definitely not, I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you run your app inside Docker, you don't have access to the host file system (i would assume that `S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/` is a directory on your local file system). Hence, you should either [mount the folder](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) that you need to write to, or write to a location which exists inside the Docker container.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm working in Windows, in Docker, under Settings>Resources>File Sharing I've added the directory 'S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/' so that it can be mounted into Docker containers.
I usually run my docker image: docker run -p 8050:8050 image_name

Comment: I tried: docker run -p 8050:8050 image_name -v S:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3 and got the error: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown. – A